# Issue with custom javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a custom regular expression which I use to detect whole numbers, fractions and floats.

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^((^[1-9]|(0\.)|(\.))([0-9]+)?((\s|\.)[0-9]+(/[0-9])?)?)$");
var quantity = 'd';
var matched = quantity.match(regEx);
alert(matched);
```

​
(The code is also found here: http://jsfiddle.net/aNb3L/ .)

The problem is that for a single letter it matches, and I can't figure out why. But for more letters it fails(which is good).

Disclaimer: I am new to regular expressions, although in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it doesn't match a single letter

Comment: I don't understand what that `/[0-9]` part is towards the end. I'm guessing it's part of the reason that you want your own recognizer.

Comment: You need to escape `\ ` characters in string literals. If you want to use a `\ ` character in a regular expression, it needs to be written as `'\\'` within the string literal. This means to match the `\ ` character with a regular expression you'd need to use `'\\\\'`.

Comment: Do you need to handle floats with exponential notation, e.g. `1.23e12`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to use straight regular expression syntax:

```
var regEx = /^((^[1-9]|(0\.)|(\.))([0-9]+)?((\s|\.)[0-9]+(\/[0-9])?)?)$/;
```

When you use the `RegExp` constructor, you have to double-up on the backslashes. As it is, your code only has single backslashes, so the `\.` subexpressions are being treated as `.` — and that's how single non-digit characters are slipping through.

Thus yours would also work this way:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^((^[1-9]|(0\\.)|(\\.))([0-9]+)?((\\s|\\.)[0-9]+(/[0-9])?)?)$");
```

This happens because the string syntax *also* uses backslash as a quoting mechanism. When your regular expression is first parsed *as a string constant*, those backslashes are stripped out if you don't double them.  When the string is then passed to the regular expression parser, they're gone.

The only time you really need to use the `RegExp` constructor is when you're building up the regular expression dynamically or when it's delivered to your code via JSON or something.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `regEx.test(quantity)` over `match` for validation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a whole number this would be your regex:

`/^(0|[1-9]\d*)$/`

Then you have to account for the possibility of a float:

`/^(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$/`

Then you have to account for the possibility of a fraction:

`/^(0|[1-9]\d*)((.\d+)|(\/[1-9]\d*)?$/`

To me this regex is much easier to read than your original, but it's up to you of course.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to regular expressions. But thank you for this one, I'll study it and if it works ok I'll use it.

Comment: Just thought I'd provide an alternative if you wanted one!